# Advice: I'm trying to make a tracking time feature in my application but when should I send the data to the backend

Tags: reactjs, laravel, api, time

I'm making a client management system in Laravel and ReactJS. I use Laravel for the backend and the api and ReactJS (with Context API) for the frontend of course.

I want to add a tracking timer into my application so the idea is that you can click on a button and select a client and it will start a timer, when you click on the stop button it will stop the timer and the time passed, is how much you spend working for that client.

My question is when should I send the time spend to the backend API?

My ideas:

1. After the users clicked on the stop button.
2. Every single minute (but with this technique the client will send a lot of requests to the backend).

**NOTE: When a user refreshes the page the timer needs to continue where it left off.**

Does anyone have some advice on how to do this?

Comment: Depends, if it should be possible to start the timer on your laptop for example and stop the timer on your phone.

Comment: For now that is not the main goal but in the future I do want to make a mobile app for my client manager so that feature would be included in the mobile app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your requirement, I guess that's fair enough when the stop button is clicked. In fact, you may capture the date-time

- once start is clicked
- once again when the stop button is clicked also find the difference between these two to identify the time consumed in your client application.

This way, refreshing the page will have no impact since these are loosely coupled.

Comment: What if the user refreshes the page without stopping the timer first, what will happen?

Comment: @Raccoon, nothing would happen, the user can even exit the application, come back and stop it. That's because we would be just taking the difference between the two timestamps.